# Full character encoding list with timeline?

Tags: unicode, encoding

I'm looking for the full character encoding list, sorted by apparition time.

Comment: If you are looking for when a character was added to Unicode, that information is part of the standard. E.g. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/version/3.0/index.htm has this in a convenient browsable catalog, but the information comes from Unicode itself.

Answer (score 2):

The official IANA [Character Sets registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xml) documents the character sets currently registered. I’m afraid there is no compilation of such information by apparition time, and the registry does not even include registration time (and apparition might be different – some encodings were widely used before they were registered).

Comment: thnks a lot, have a nice day